# Updating API URL call with user input in REACT

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Hi guys I wanted to know how to update my existing API url call with updated user input and fetch the new updated data. I am new to react couldn't figure out it. I want to grab user input and add it in the API url and fetch it and get the updated data. But I don't know if I should update it every time new props component receives or use some other kind of method?
Am I supposed to use react-router here(I didn't learn it yet)? Desperately need help. Thank you
Here is my code

```
   let cityName;
export class App extends React.Component{
constructor() {
  super();
  this.state = {
    city: '',
    temp: '',
    description: '',
    weatherIconId: '',
    pressure: '',
    wind: '',
    humidity: ''
  }
  this.handlechange = this.handlechange.bind(this);
}

handlechange(e) {
  this.setState({city: e.target.value});
}



componentDidMount() {
  cityName = this.state.city;
  const apikey = 'ec192677d39c9ad44049bb5c5a477b1b';
  fetch(`https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=${cityName}
    &APPiD=${apikey}`)
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => this.setState({
      description: data['weather'][0]['description'],
      temp: Math.floor(data['main']['temp'] - 273.15),
      wind: data['speed'] }) )
    .catch(error => console.log('failed to fetch', error));
}

  render() {
    return(<div>
<input type='text' onChange={this.handlechange}/>
<h1> Your city is {this.state.city} and temperature is {this.state.temp}
and its {this.state.description}</h1>
      </div>);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are calling the API only when the componentDidMount and it happens once as soon as the component has been mounted. 
If you want to change city you should handle the API call inside

```
handlechange(e) {
  // call here the API and if the call goes well update the state

 }
```